How to confirm that a QFT is a conformal field theory (CFT) at the quantum level?
My question is: Given a QFT, what's the usual/reliable/logical way to confirm that it's a CFT at the quantum level? Here are some explanations about why I ask this question.
I have learned a lot about conformal field theory (CFT) but am getting more and more confused. It seems to me that assuming a theory is a CFT allows us to derive many properties, such as the simple form of two-point correlation functions.
However, it's not clear to me how we determine whether a QFT is a CFT before invoking conformal invariance. For example, the massless $\phi^4$ theory in 4D has no intrinsic scale in its classical action:
$$
S = \int \mathrm{d}^4 x \left(-\frac{1}{2} (\partial\phi)^2 - g \phi^4\right),
$$
but is it a CFT at the quantum level? I heard that one should compute the $\beta$ function and related quantities, but most textbooks seem to focus on transformations and symmetry generators, not the $\beta$ function. This leaves me confused about the relationship between these concepts and the overall logic.
Thanks in advance for any helpful discussion and answers.

P.S.
After asking this question, I even wonder how we know relativistic invariance is still there in a QFT, since I was told that conformal invariance can be "broken" from classical theory to quantum theory.

The thing that breaks conformal symmetry in the transition from classical field theory to quantum field theory is renormalization. Essentially, you can think of it as being because observables take the form $$ O_{full} = O_{renorm} + O_{diverge}.$$ $O_{diverge}$ is the infinite part we subtract away with counter terms. $O_{renorm}$ is the thing we actually measure, not $O_{full}$.
Because of the classical conformal symmetry, $O_{full}$ is independent of scale. But there might be a scale dependence in each term $O_{renorm}$ and $O_{diverge}$ that cancels out. How do we know if this is the case? Well, we can compute how $O_{renorm}$ changes with scale. But that's exactly what a beta function is: $$\beta(O_{renorm}) = \mu \frac{d O_{renorm}}{d \mu}.$$
So the scale invariance of the quantum observables only holds if the beta functions vanish, essentially by definition of the beta functions.

Thanks for your answer. But it seems that my question is not answered.
To make it clear, the criteria of a CFT is its $\beta$ function? Or more specifically, is the massless $\phi^4$ theory a CFT or not? How about when interaction $g=0$? What's the definitive criteria to say it's a CFT or not? By calculating $\beta$ function, is that what you mean? Thank you very much.
